# Libgdx Array<> how to get last item?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d

I want to change Y position of "bucket", when camera Y position is higher than "last created bucket" Y position: There is my code in "create()" method

```
buckets = new Array<Bucket>();
for(int i=1;i<BUCKET_COUNT;i++){
    buckets.add(new Bucket(world,(rand.nextInt((int)W)-45)/PPM,BUCKET_MARGIN*i/PPM));
}
```

And I am doing like this in "render()" method:

```
for(Bucket bucket : buckets){
    if(cam.position.y > buckets.peek().getBody().getPosition().y){
        bucket.repos(rand.nextInt((int)W)/PPM,buckets.size+BUCKET_MARGIN/PPM);
    }
}
```

**repos():**

```
public void repos(float x, float y){
    setPosition(x, y);//Bucket class is extends Sprite
}
```

But it doesn't work and I don't know how to solve this problem

I want to know how to get **last** item from those array?

Comment: define "doesn't work"

Comment: I mean. There is nothing changed when cam.posY > posY

Comment: you look at `buckets.peek()`, but you change `bucket`. Those are not the same object.

Comment: `Sprite` don't have `getBody()` method, what is it ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this,

```
if(cam.position.y > buckets.peek().getPosition().y){
     for(Bucket bucket : buckets){
        bucket.repos(rand.nextInt((int)W)/PPM,buckets.size+BUCKET_MARGIN/PPM);
    }
}
```

In this y position of buckets are not properly specified because according to your code all bucket set to particular y position.

**EDIT**

```
if(cam.position.y > buckets.peek().getPosition().y){
    for(Bucket bucket : buckets){
            bucket.repos(rand.nextInt((int)W)/PPM,cam.position.y+bucket.getPositon().y);
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Take a look of this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mn5rjsxWH_E&index=25&list=PLXY8okVWvwZ0JOwHiH1TntAdq-UDPnC2L), I think it may be helpful for you.

Comment: No. it doesn't work. I want to change first bucket position to upper than last.(there are 3 buckets)

Comment: only first bucket ?

Comment: maybe first. I am just want to create platforms like in Doodle Jump, Where buckets changing their position or ( adding new Objects into array and deleting the first item )

Comment: if you're not changing position of all bucket then `cam.position.y > buckets.peek().getPosition().y` always return true and if you change position of all bucket then at sudden all bucket appears forward.

Comment: `cam.position.y` is in meter or in pixels ?

Comment: If I am not wrong your `Bucket` is `Sprite` that having physics body. and you're updating position of Bucket through his body, then there is no meaning of `setPosition(x, y);` inside your `repos` method.