# How to add new body into ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d

I have Array of 3 "platforms" like in "Doodle Jump" game:

```
buckets = new Array<Bucket>();

    for(int i=1;i<BUCKET_COUNT;i++){
        buckets.add(new Bucket(this,(rand.nextInt((int)W)-45),BUCKET_MARGIN*i));
    }
//BUCKET_COUNT = 3;
//BUCKET_MARGIN = 220;
```

I want to add or reposition first platform's position to "last
platform's position in array" + BUCKET_MARGIN - **When** player's or camera's position highter than last platfotm

Any idea how to realize this function?

Comment: Note: iterating with starting index=1 in this example will only create two Buckets.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Libgdx Array<> how to get last item?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43877394/libgdx-array-how-to-get-last-item)